# How to use vi.spyOn wrapper.vm typescript error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vitest

Bellow my complete code

TestTableFooter.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const page = ref(1);
const isDisabled = computed(() => {
  return page.value > 1;
});

const handlePageClick = async (page: number, disabled: boolean) => {
  if (disabled) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('fetch data from page', page);
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <a role="link" class="i-first" @click="handlePageClick(page + 1, isDisabled)">&nbsp;</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

TestTableFooter.spec.ts

```
import { describe, it, expect, beforeEach, vi } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

import TestTableFooter from '../TestTableFooter.vue';

describe('ResultTableFooter is rendering properly the first page', () => {
  // beforeEach(() => {});

  it('should simulate click on next with a spy', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(TestTableFooter);
    const mockHandlePageClick = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handlePageClick');
    mockHandlePageClick.mockImplementation((...args) => {
      console.log('Mock click handler with', { args });
    });
    const nextPageLink = wrapper.find('.i-first');
    await nextPageLink.trigger('click');
    expect(mockHandlePageClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockHandlePageClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2, false);
  });
});
```

I have a type script error on the spec line `const mockHandlePageClick = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handlePageClick');`
The `wrapper.vm` don't have the `handlePageClick` property.

Could you help me please to solve this issue ?